# How to create an object with two key/value pairs from two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got to separate arrays that I am wanting to combine and create an object with two distinct key / value pairs. Is there anyway to create a single object with two key/value pairs from these two arrays? Structure and example of object I'm trying to create are below.

My arrays are structured as follows:

**formLabel Array**

```
const labelNames = this.state.formLabels;
*Output*
0: "Name"
1: "Prefix"
2: "First"
3: "Middle"
4: "Last"
5: "Suffix"
6: "Company Name"
7: "Email"
8: "Date Submitted"
9: "Lead Source"
10: "Owner Name"
11: "Owner Email"
```

**formKeys Array**

```
const labelKeys = this.state.formKeys;
*Output*
0: "1"
1: "1.2"
2: "1.3"
3: "1.4"
4: "1.6"
5: "1.8"
6: "4"
7: "5"
8: "6"
9: "7"
10: "8"
11: "9"
```

**How can I go about creating an object like such?**

```
0: {id: "LABEL KEY WOULD GO HERE", label: "LABEL NAME WOULD GO HERE"}
1: {id: "LABEL KEY WOULD GO HERE", label: "LABEL NAME WOULD GO HERE"}
... etc
```

Comment: Both `id` and `label` have "label" in them?

Comment: Sounds as if a tool like [`zip`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip) is involved, but the question is hazy enough it's not clear.

Comment: Are both arrays of the same length?

Comment: @tadman I'm not quite sure where you're getting that information from the question.. There are two arrays, labelKeys and labelNames. The values of each of those arrays would be input into an object with two key / pair values. Lodash is not involved in this.

Comment: It'd help make the question clearer by showing JavaScript code, not things like "stuff goes here" and input in a form that's not code and leaves ambiguity as to what it is. An array? A text file with that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have parallel arrays, you can map one of the arrays to a list of objects containing the current key and label (by index).

```js
const labelNames = [
  "Name"         , "Prefix"     , "First"          ,
  "Middle"       , "Last"       , "Suffix"         ,
  "Company Name" , "Email"      , "Date Submitted" ,
  "Lead Source"  , "Owner Name" , "Owner Email"
];

const labelKeys = [
  "1"   , "1.2" , "1.3" ,
  "1.4" , "1.6" , "1.8" ,
  "4"   , "5"   , "6"   ,
  "7"   , "8"   , "9"
];

const res = labelKeys.map((key, idx) => ({ id: key, label: labelNames[idx] }));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You could create a reusable function as well:

```js
const labelNames = [
  "Name"         , "Prefix"     , "First"          ,
  "Middle"       , "Last"       , "Suffix"         ,
  "Company Name" , "Email"      , "Date Submitted" ,
  "Lead Source"  , "Owner Name" , "Owner Email"
];

const labelKeys = [
  "1"   , "1.2" , "1.3" ,
  "1.4" , "1.6" , "1.8" ,
  "4"   , "5"   , "6"   ,
  "7"   , "8"   , "9"
];

const zip = (fn, ...arr) => arr[0].map((_, i) => fn(...arr.map(v => v[i])));

console.log(zip((id, label) => ({ id, label }), labelKeys, labelNames));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in this question my best guess is this:

```js
const labelNames = [
    "Name",
    "Prefix",
    "First",
    "Middle",
    "Last",
    "Suffix",
    "Company Name",
    "Email",
    "Date Submitted",
    "Lead Source",
    "Owner Name",
    "Owner Email",
];


const labelKeys = [
    "1",
    "1.2",
    "1.3",
    "1.4",
    "1.6",
    "1.8",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
];

const newArrayWithObjects = labelNames.map((label,i) => ({ label, id: labelKeys[i] }));

console.log(newArrayWithObjects);
```